# Use selected item id from selected_tag in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

**view:**

```
<%= select_tag 'template_id', options_from_collection_for_select(@templates, "id", "title", @template.id), class: "form-control", id: "template_select" %>

$('#template_select').on('change', function() {
   <% sections = Section.where(is_template: true, template_id: selected_template_id ) %>
});
```

How can I use the selected item id from the tag in my sql query's *template_id*?

Comment: Could You pls create separate code blocks for HTML and JS if they are located in separate files?
And if we are technical, I would say that it is an Active Record query method rather then SQL query as it`s not a raw SQL query.

Comment: Yes, you are right, it is an active record query :) _select_tag_ and the _js_ are in the same file. I think the way I do it isn't quite kosher. Because even if I get the _:selected value_ I cannot use it inside the query. Maybe there is another more rails way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR** - look in the DOM for value attribute and query it with JS

You could try finding HTML `input` tag (with a `hidden` attribute) in the DOM which in turn should contain value attribute and then simply query it with JavaScript.

If the `input` tag is not visible near the `select` tag, just look for a value attribute near/inside the `select` tag which should contain the selected `template` `id`.